# How to write something underneath \min?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, stack

How to type this expression, where has `\min` on top and `\forall` at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: I'd remove the universal quantifier.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The bottom part is a TeX subscript (like `\sum`):

```
\min_{\forall s \in S_j} q_k(s)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

#### Textstyle vs. Displaystyle

Compile the following code sequence to understand the difference between textstyle and displaystyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sample{\min\nolimits_{\forall s \in S_j} q_k(s)}
\begin{document}
\noindent Text-Textstyle: \(\sample\)\\
          Text-Displaystyle: \(\displaystyle\sample\)
  \[
    \textrm{Text-Textstyle: }\textstyle\sample
  \]\[
    \textrm{Display-Displaystyle: }\sample
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output code]

You can also use `\nolimits` and `\limits` to force textstyle limits and displaystyle limits respectively:

```
\min\limits_{\forall s \in S_j} q_k(s)
```

Comment: hi, it seems this is not in the same format as the picture in the question

Comment: @william007: how it comes out depends on whether you are on displaystyle or textstyle; try inside a `\[...\]`. Qrrbrb..: it's a TeX subscript (/nitpick ;)).

Comment: @william007 morbusg is right. I've updated my answer to explain the difference between textstyle and displaystyle.