# How to put the equation number at the end

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations

How to put the equation number at the end like below

[image]

Comment: `begin{equation} y =x \end{equation}`?

Comment: ...also, following [How to type such expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73226/5764), use `Q\min` rather than `Qmin`.

Comment: yes you are right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, numbered equations are get by using the numbered equation environments (`equation` or with package `amsmath`: `gather`, `align`, …).
Unless some option is set (`fleqn`) the equation numbers are put at the right. Package `amsmath` is also a bit cleverer by measuring the equation first and moves the equation number out of the way right below the equation, if the equation is too wide.

The `min'` is a little bit tricky if `\min` is used, because `\min'` prints the prime at the wrong place in displayed equations:

> [image: min with wrong prime]

`\min{}'` does not help, because the distance becomes too large.
`\min\nolimits'` helps in this case without subscripts.
The following example defines a new operator `\minp` that also supports the case, where the subscript goes below the operator name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minp}{min^\prime}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Q\minp(k) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} Q\min(j,k)        
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]