# How to use \min in equation

Tags: math-mode

I have the following problem when I want use minimum 
among some numbers.

$\min_{1}$ works well but

$$\min_{1} $$ or

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\min_{1} 
\end{eqnarray*}
```

are looking very odd.

Comment: You're probably looking for `\min\nolimits_{1}`. Side note: `$$...$$` is deprecated in LaTeX, and don't use `eqnarray`: prefer `align` and friends from `amsmath` instead.

Comment: What exactly *is* `\min_{1}` in this case? There is a reason why `\min` behaves like this in displayed context.

Comment: it is conventional to put the limit underneath, same as with `\sum`, in things like `\min_{0\leq x \leq N} f(x)`

Comment: see the auto-linked question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/how-to-write-something-underneath-min?rq=1