# Sum indices besides the sign in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

How can I get the indices of a sum sign to appear **besides** the sum in **math mode**?

I know that this is default for inline mode, how can I set this for math mode locally (preferably w/o additional packages etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The link shown above deals both with how to show inline math as if it were display math and how to show display math as if it were inline math.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/how-to-write-something-underneath-min.

Comment: @Mico Cheers! I couldn't find this question, only the one where people wanted indices below the sum in inline mode. Should I delete my question then?

Comment: @JDecou - No need to delete your query! Just because a query gets closed as a dupe doesn’t imply that it’s not a good query. :-)