# How to fix $lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}$ in an itemize environment?

Tags: typography

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} \phi(t)=0, \quad \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} \phi^2(t)=0, \quad \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} S(t)=0, \quad$

\item two. 

\item three.

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How would I put $t\rightarrow \infty$ under the $\lim$?

Comment: Change `\lim` to `\lim\limits`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to write something underneath `\min`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73226/5764)

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use `\to` instead of `\rightarrow`. In this view the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \phi(t)=0, 
      \quad \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \phi^2(t)=0, 
      \quad \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} S(t)=0, \quad$
\item two. 
\item three.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]